# How to write to HBase from Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

Referring to my other question "Writing to HBase from Spark Streaming", I was advised to follow https://www.mapr.com/blog/spark-streaming-hbase in order to write to HBase from Spark Streaming and that's what I did (with modification according to my need), when running Spark-submit, there is no error but also that data is not written into HBase, I'll show you the code if you could please figure out if I did something wrong and how to correct it :

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val jobConfig: JobConf = new JobConf(conf)
    jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
    jobConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "tabName")
Dstream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
            rdd.map(Convert.toPut).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig))
```

with :

```
object Convert{
  def toPut (parametre: (String,String)): (ImmutableBytesWritable, Put) = {
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(1))
    put.add(Bytes.toBytes("colfamily"), Bytes.toBytes(parametre._1), Bytes.toBytes(parametre._2))
    return (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(1)), put)
  }
```

Could you please help me find out what I'm doing wrong here ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you show the full codes?

Comment: @zsxwing that's almost it, the only tthing missing is the imports and what the Dstream is

Comment: Did you start the StreamingContext?

Comment: Could you print the content of `rdd` to check if there is any input?

Comment: yes, I started the context with :
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination() 
and when I print the rdd it comes out so there is definitely an input, that's why I put the configuration of HBase, maybe there's a mistake there